# python regex issue matching links within td element

Tags: python, html, regex, html-table

I'm trying to use regex to match a cell in a table, but the problem is not all cells follow the same pattern. For example, the td may take this format:

```
<td><a href="page101010.html">PageNumber</a></td>
```

or this format:

```
<td align="left" ></td>
```

Basically, the hyperlink part within the td is not present in all, its just in some.

I tried matching this situation using the below python regex code, but its failing.

```
match = re.search(r'<td align="left" ><?a?.+\>?(.+)\<?\/?a?\>?\<\/td\>', tdlink)
```

I just need 'match' to find the part enclosed in () above. However I'm getting syntax error or a None Object message.

Where am I going wrong?

Comment: Basically i m using the <?a?.+\>? to see check and act when the link is present/not.

Comment: First place you're going wrong - [using regexp on HTML](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags).

Comment: +1 to @Izkata, you can parse HTML in the proper way with Python.

Comment: Do you have to use regex for this, or can you use an HTML parsing library like [lxml](http://lxml.de/) or [BeautifulSoup](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/)?

Comment: i have to use regex. i know i m wrong with the <?a?.+\>? part of the line, as the .+     (dotplus) will spoil the previous use of '?' and fail there. But i have been thinking about generalising as much as possible.. hmm..

Comment: @user1644208: Why do you have to use regex? It is *very much* the wrong tool for the job.

Comment: yup, i think i would be better off using some string operations on the output, rather than generalizing it. (I have to have to use reges :(( )

Comment: @user1644208 Your insistence makes this sound like homework.  I think you should tell your teacher that he/she is also wrong, if possible.  (Careful; it may hurt your grade depending on how they take it...)

Answer (score 6):

You are using a regular expression, and matching XML with such expressions get too complicated, too fast.

Use a HTML parser instead, Python has several to choose from:

- [ElementTree](http://docs.python.org/library/xml.etree.elementtree.html) is part of the standard library
- [BeautifulSoup](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/) is a popular 3rd party library
- [lxml](http://lxml.de/) is a fast and feature-rich C-based library.

ElementTree example:

```
from xml.etree import ElementTree

tree = ElementTree.parse('filename.html')
for elem in tree.findall('tr'):
    print ElementTree.tostring(elem)
```

Comment: +1 BeautifulSoup.  `soup = BeautifulSoup('<td><a href="page101010.html">PageNumber</a></td>\n<td align="left" ></td>'); [tag.text for tag in soup.findAll("td")]` returns `[u'PageNumber', '']`, and pretty much everything else is similarly simple.